# Is it possible to use Copilot sticky sender with a Flow

Tags: twilio

I would like to use a flow created in Studio with some Copilot features like Scaler and Sticky sender.

I've a flow created already using Studio, as well as few numbers added to a messaging service, Sticky sender and Scaler are enabled on this service.

I would like to use this messaging service with the created flow, so i don't have to worry about balancing the usage of those assigned phone numbers myself.

When I configure a number I can only assign a messaging service (which i prefer) or a work flow, but not both at the same time. Although it would make sense if I can assign the flow to a messaging service.

Looking at Twilio Client for C#, i see that ExecutionResource.CreateAsync takes  a from phone number as required parameter, so it doesn't seem like this is a possible options to have a flow linked to a messaging service.

I'm wondering if there is any workarounds, like having a function maybe to pass a phone number from the messaging service to the flow? or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Malek, you can also set the From to a messaging service using the From.

[Executions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/execution)

from:

"The Twilio phone number to send messages or initiate calls from during the Flow Execution, available as variable {{flow.channel.address}}"

- Should have the added sentence: "You can also use a Messaging Service SID."

Comment: i'm not sure i get your answer right, you see here is an example from Twilio docs to run a flow [C# example](https://github.com/twilio/sample-code/blob/master/studio/v1/execution/create-default/create-default.5.x.cs)

ExecutionResource.Create only accepts type PhoneNumber for from parameter, but i don't want to use a phone number, i would the Messaging Service to manage selecting a phone number for me

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

What you want to do in this instance is to configure the number with a messaging service, then set the messaging service Inbound request URL to the flow's REST API trigger URL, which should look a bit like:

```
https://webhooks.twilio.com/v1/Accounts/<account_sid>/Flows/<flow_sid>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @philnash for your answer, it partially answers my question, now I get how this will help trigger the flow. What's missing how do I make the flow now use the messaging service to reply back to the users. I still don't want to have one phone number configured per flow, and using sticky number from Copilot i assume this will not result in random numbers replying back to the same user